# How to decrypt MultiBit private key with 128 bytes line and 52 bytes line?

Tags: multibit, recover-private-key, private-key-format

I want to recover my bitcoin private key stored by MultiBit. I've written down private key as text while using MultiBit classic. I don't remember how I get the text of private key. The text consists of two line. First line has 128 characters and starts with `U` and contains `+`. Second line has 52 characters and starts with `q`, contains `/`.

As far as I know, the text may be encrypted. And I also wrote down password, so I assume I can decrypt the text with the password, but I don't know how.

I've tried the instruction of [Export and limited import of private keys](https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/multibit/wiki/Export%20and%20limited%20import%20of%20private%20keys) with pasting the text to a file and executed the `openssl` command. However, I've got `bad decrypt` message and 64 bytes result file. It doesn't seem successful.

I want to how to decrypt my private key text and get valid private key.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here: [Decrypting keys from Multibit](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/103121/119317)

The way [Export and limited import of private keys](https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/multibit/wiki/Export%20and%20limited%20import%20of%20private%20keys)  explained is almost right, but it's missing a parameter, `-md md5`. I added that and it worked.